# Entity Manager not created (with Google App Engine + JPA)?

Tags: java, servlets, jpa, entitymanager

I am experiencing a problem when trying to add an object (JPA) in the datastore. I am deploying it to App Engine. I've tried to perform some very basic debug, since I am new to web development, by trying to perform prints before and after each step from where I thought my problem could be. Apparently, the problems seems to be the fact that Entity Manager is not created, therefore (obviously) the addition in the database is not performed. Here is my code:

```
         // all the parameters are previously initialized.
         public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
         Symptoms aSymptoms = new Symptoms(thePatientId,theHeadacke,theMorningHeadacke,theDiziness,theFatigue,theMuscularFatigue,
            theTinitus,theVisualImpairment,theWeightLoss,theHeartPalpitation,thePallor,theWeightProblems,theUpperBodyObesity,
            theBrutalIncreaseDiastolic,theLumbarPain,theFever,thePolyuria,theSweating,thePositionChangeDiziness);
    // using a SymptomsDAOJPA object I can perform add in the datastore.
    SymptomsDAO dao = new SymptomsDAOJPA();

    try {
        // Save the symptom.
        out.println("Entered try in doPost.");
        dao.add(aSymptoms);
        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        out.println("Saved symptom.");
        out.println(aSymptoms);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_EXPECTATION_FAILED);
        out.println("Problem saving symptom.");
    }
 }
```

The add(sSymptom) method is the following:

```
        @Override
public void add(Symptoms setSymptoms) {
    EntityManager em = null;
    System.out.println("Entity Manager is null so far.");
    try {
        em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
        System.out.println("Created Entity Manager.");
        SymptomsJPA setSymtomsJPA = new SymptomsJPA(setSymptoms);
        System.out.println("Created SymptomsJPA object to be added in the database.");
        em.persist(setSymtomsJPA);
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }

}
```

The last message that is printed is: Entity Manager is null so far.
Therefore, my assumption is that this is what goes wrong:

```
          em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
```

Here you have my EMF class:

```
     public final class EMF {
private static final EntityManagerFactory emfInstance = Persistence
    .createEntityManagerFactory("transactions-optional");

private EMF() {
// intentionally empty
}
public static EntityManagerFactory get() {
return emfInstance;
}
```

}

And my persistance.xml (partly) is:

```
<persistence-unit name="transactions-optional">
    <provider>org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I have no idea why my Entity Manager is not created. I have been using this code and it worked, but now it doesn't and I don't know what I am missing. I really appreciate any thoughts with respect to this.

Thank you.

Comment: errm, if an EntityManager is "not created" then it is null, then you get NPE. But you don't mention that. So we assume that EntityManager is created, hence you should look in the LOG, or put a catch for an exception in the creation

Comment: Thank you for you answer. There is no exception, I have just checked the log and nothing. I am confused, because it prints what is before creating the Entity Manager, but it doesn't print what's after.

Comment: the log obviously does print lots ... if you put it at DEBUG level. And if it doesn't get to your next debug line then it throws a Throwable (because nothing else is possible in Java)